# Contact form rejected by server

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am pretty new at this so I apologize up front. Sorry for asking this question for the millionth time but I can't get my contact form to mail. I receive server error 500. I tried to find out what that meant without success. I have looked though all of the other posts here without success. Thanks for helping.

Here's my html:
Contact Form -->

```
<form id="contact-form" action="sendEmail.php" method="post">

<p>
<span>
<input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name" required>
</span>
</p>

<p>
<span>
<input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required>
</span>
</p>

<p>
<span>
<textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
</span>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message">
</p>

</form>
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php

    // Form Variables
    $sender_name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $sender_email = $_POST['email'];
    $sender_message = $_POST['message'];

    // Configuration Vaiables
    $receiving_email = 'name@email.com'; // Replace this with your own email address
    $receiver_name = 'name'; // replace with your name
    $email_subject = 'Email Sent from Contact Form'; // replace with any default title

    // Require swiftMailer Library
    require_once('lib/classes/swiftMailer/swift_required.php');

    // Create the transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.rickstrode.com') // enter SMTP address
      ->setPort(587) // enter SMTP port
      ->setEncryption('ssl') // enter encryption mode
      ->setUsername('name@email.com') // enter SMTP username
      ->setPassword('abcd1234') // enter SMTP password
      ;

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a Message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($email_subject)
      ->setFrom(array($sender_email => $sender_name))
      ->setTo(array($receiving_email, $receiving_email => $receiver_name))
      ->setBody($sender_message)
      ;

    // Send the Message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    // Success and Failure Message
    if ($result) {
        echo "Congratulations, We've received your email. We'll be in touch as soon as we possibly can!";
    } else {
        echo "Unfortunately, Something went wrong while sending the message, Please try again!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure swift mailer is installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP server name is incorrect

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.rickstrode.com')
```

should be

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.rickstrode.com')
```